# HTML table won't update after entering values using PHP POST method

Tags: php, html, database, post

I have a database with course IDs and their corresponding course names. I'm trying to create a filter using a dropdown menu that filters the displayed courses.

Here's the code -

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php // sqltest.php

include 'header.php';
include 'nav.php';

require_once 'login.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if (!$conn) {
 die ('Fail to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());   
}


echo '<form action="" method="post">
<select name="Course Name">
<option value="All" selected="selected">All course names</option>
<option value="Introduction to Data Science">Introduction to Data Science</option>
<option value="Database Management Systems">Database Management Systems</option>
<option value="Data Visualization">Data Visualization</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" />
</form>';

$cname = isset($_POST['Course Name']) ? $_POST['Course Name'] : 'All';

if(isset($_POST)) {

 if ($cname == 'Introduction to Data Science') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE Cname='Introduction to Data'";
 } elseif ($cname == 'Database Management Systems') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE Cname='Database Management'";
 } elseif ($cname == 'Data Visualization') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE Cname='Data Visualization'";
 } elseif ($cname == 'All') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses";
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
 echo '<br>Available courses for hardcoded student 000-01-0002<br><br>';

 echo '<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Course ID</th>
        <th>Course Name</th>
        <th>Add</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>';

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>
    <td>' . $row['cid'] . '</td>
    <td>' . $row['Cname'] . '</td>
    <td><a href="addClass.php?Cid=' . $row['cid'] . '">Add</a></td>
    </tr>';
  }
 }


echo '
</tbody>
</table>
</body>';
```

It displays all the courses when the page first loads but picking any one of the courses and clicking on submit does not change the initial table at all.

Comment: Answer below. Post field names should not have spaces or dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space in Course Name post field. It's not recognized as a valid POST field in your isset check because of the space.

Make it name="course_name" or something on select field.

Comment: Wow that was far more trivial than I expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I almost didn't catch it, but most of your code looked fine, so I started thinking it was an SQL error... but then I realized you said it worked fine w/o a search, so I knew the results/columns were correct, so I figured it must be syntax. Thanks for marking it as answer :)